# Google Play Games y GoogleMobileAds do not work together in Unity 5

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm working on a game in **Unity3D** and integrated services have **Google Play games**, but when importing the plug **GoogleMobileAds**, it throws me errors.

I use:

- Unity 5.3.5f1 Personal,
- Google Play Games Plugin 0.9.34,
- Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v3.1.0.

The two plugins work well alone, but when I import both plugins, I get these two errors:

> Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/PlayServicesResolver.cs(146,56): error CS0433: The imported type `Google.JarResolver.Dependency' is defined multiple times

and

> Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/GPGSDependencies.cs(37,23): error CS0433: The imported type `Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport' is defined multiple times

How do I fix this?

Comment: while importing admob unity plugin, just uncheck googleplayservices

Comment: or just Delete GPG...bla bla bla... file if you have duplicates

Answer (score 6):

You can try to remove JarResolverLib.dll file in Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/   .