# Unity - Google play Services vs. Appodeal

Tags: c#, google-play-services, unity-game-engine, ads

I'm using GPS plugin for a mobile game and I want there ads, so I decided to add Appodeal. First I've imported Appodeal and than GPS. But,when I finish the Import they show two errors that I couldn't find any solution.

Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/IResolver.cs(74,27): error CS0433: The imported type `Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport' is defined multiple times

Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/PlayServicesResolver.cs(146,56): error CS0433: The imported type `Google.JarResolver.Dependency' is defined multiple times

Someone here to help me please? Thank you..

Comment: When trying to import Appodeal, try unchecking Google Play Service. Or as stated in this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40346876/5995040),  "remove JarResolverLib.dll file in `Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/`."

Comment: There is also a provided solution in the Github - [Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport & Google.JarResolver.Dependency defined multiple times](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/306), delete the contents of the `Assets/PlayServicesResolver` directory within your Unity project and re-import the latest version of the Ad plugin you are using (in his case Google Mobile Ads plugin). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Many plugins will try to install PlayServicesResolver into your project Assets folder. They usually handle multiple versions on their own and will prompt a message asking if you want to delete obsolete files.

I'm not sure why but that doesn't happen with Appodeal, what I usually do is just delete Assets/PlayServicesResolver before importing any unity package that comes with it.

## Manually installing PlayServicesResolver

Another thing you could do is install PlayServicesResolver manually and like Mr.Rebot mentioned in his comment, uncheck PlayServicesResolver when importing plugins.

If you already have a folder Assets/PlayServicesResolver delete it first.
You can download the latest Resolver from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver).

Open it to import it into your project.

[image: Importing PlayServicesResolver]

You can then import Appodeal and make sure you uncheck PlayServicesResolver as shown next:

[image]

As you can see Appodeal was trying to install an older version in my case.